# How to specify alternative return type alongside with generic?

Tags: python, typing

I have following function signature:

```
def get(key, default=None):
    pass
```

**I want to specify return type to be as default type, but if default is `None` then it should be `str`:**

```
T = TypeVar('T')
def get(key: str, default: Optional[T]=None) -> T:
    pass
```

^ this solves first problem, but I can't figure out how to tell linter that alternative return type should be `str` and not `Any`.

I also tried `-> Union[str, T]` and no luck.

As @jonrsharpe suggested I tried to use `@overload` decorator:

```
from typing import TypeVar, overload


T = TypeVar('T')


@overload
def get(key: str, default=None) -> str: ...


@overload
def get(key: str, default: T) -> T: ...


def get(key: str, default: T=None) -> T:
    if default is None:
        return ''
    print(key)
    return 2


def main():
    a = get('key')
    a = get('key', None)
    a = get('key', 1)
    a = get('key', 1.23)
    a = get('key', b'fd')
    a = get('key', 'fds')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But because of `default` is `None` (by default) detected return type is now Union[str, T].

#### Final edit

Should be `def get(key: str, default: Optional[T]=None) -> T` + overloads. Now everything is fine.

Comment: it's not java, i can't create 2 function with same name but different signature

Comment: You can define an [`overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload), though.

Comment: this might work, i will try

Comment: @jonrsharpe i tried so hard, but don't got so far...

Comment: Why does the *default value* change the return type in any case? Shouldn't the default type be irrelevant when the default is not needed? It seems that ``Union[str, T]`` is the correct return type based on your description and the signature.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi you are right. I fixed it by specifying concrete type for `default` (`Optional[T]` instead of just `T`) in main function. w/o type at all it also works

Comment: That *should* be the return type, you either get a string or a T.